# Rails Active Storage image link in render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How could I render a json with my posts (each one have an attachment) with their image url?

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  render json: { posts: @posts }, include: :image # Image is the attachment
end
```

I have this, but I know this is not going to work due to I need the image URL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

json.jbuilder view files can help here

> app/view/posts/index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @posts, partial: 'post', as: :post
```

> app/view/posts/_post.json.jbuilder

```
json.id post.id
json.image_url url_for(post.image) if post.image.attached?
//all other fields you need
```

Comment: as you are using active storage `url_for(post.image)` is the method you are looking for to get the url

Comment: if you guys want a complete path use `rails_blob_url(post.image)` instead because `url_for(post.image)` gives no hostname in the generated url